# Is there any way to use istreambuf_iterator to read a specific length?

Tags: c++, stl, istream-iterator

I'm writing my files like this:

```
std::ofstream os; // declared somewhere earlier
std::vector<char> vec; // declared somewhere earlier

std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> oi(os);
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), oi);
```

So naturaly I was wondering if there was a similar way to read let's say 5 bytes using the `std::istream_iterator` or `std::istreambuf_iterator`, however since they don't support the `operator+` I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

For example I imagined a soludion close to this:

```
std::istream_iterator<char> ii(file);
std::copy(ii, ii + 5, vec.begin());
```

Is there any way to do this in C++14?

PS: I want a solution using STL, so using `boost` is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::copy_n` instead of `std::copy`.

```
std::copy_n(ii, 5, vec.begin());
```

However, this is a bit unsafe since it will keep trying to read even if the stream is exhausted. If that is of concern to you, then you will either have to use a lower level construct like a basic for loop, or a library with more advanced range handling capabilities, like Eric Niebler's excellent [range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

Comment: ok, so if I get it correctly the function will block if there are not enough bytes to read? Just curious, my stream will have a guaranteed number of bytes, so this is not a problem.

Comment: @tofiffe: No, it won't block. It will just fill the remaining characters with junk. (actually, I believe it will just repeat the last successfully read character over and over, though I'm not sure if that is guaranteed).

Comment: nice, seems it's far more usefull than I expected :D

Comment: Dereferencing an end-of-stream iterator is UB.